# Fastlane Match - get all provisioning profiles with a single run

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, fastlane, fastlane-match

When I run `fastlane match` inside the app's project directory it gets executed with `development: true` parameter by default, thus fetching only a development certificate and provisioning profile.

I have to run the command multiple times to refresh all the certificates and profiles, for example:

```
fastlane match adhoc
fastlane match development
fastlane match appstore
```

Is there any way to run command only once to fetch all of the mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the `match` command here:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/match/lib/match/commands_generator.rb

You can see the acceptable arguments:

```
  command :run do |c|
    c.syntax = 'fastlane match'
    c.description = Match::DESCRIPTION

    FastlaneCore::CommanderGenerator.new.generate(Match::Options.available_options, command: c)

    c.action do |args, options|
      if args.count > 0
        FastlaneCore::UI.user_error!("Please run `fastlane match [type]`, 
        allowed values: development, adhoc, enterprise  or appstore")
      end

      params = FastlaneCore::Configuration.create(Match::Options.available_options, options.__hash__)
      params.load_configuration_file("Matchfile")
      Match::Runner.new.run(params)
    end
  end
```

For readability:

> development, adhoc, enterprise  or appstore

As you mentioned, the [default value will be development](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/#parameters).

With all of that out of the way, it is not possible to provide a *single* argument to fetch all of them. However, you can try the following as a single command:

```
fastlane match "adhoc" | fastlane match "development" | fastlane match "appstore"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems, that it's impossible to fetch all of them with one command. My concern was to use a single command to save time. While your solution definitely means less typing, each of the fetches will require a separate login event, which takes time.

Comment: No problem, sorry it cannot accomplish exactly what you like. However, the maintainer is really good about adding features, so perhaps you can suggest doing so, if it has not been done already?